# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join') when calling API using HttpClient Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling my API from a service class I created called ApiService. Every time I try I get the same error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')
    at http.mjs:1728:85
    at http.mjs:273:29
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.mjs:273:14)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.mjs:1728:25)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:25)
    at Observable.js:31:30
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:9)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:22:21)
    at doInnerSub (mergeInternals.js:19:44)
```

Here's the relevant part of ApiService:

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  apiCall(type: string, path: string, params: string[], data: any, headers?: HttpHeaders) {

        let result = new Observable<any>();
    
        if (params.length) {
          for (const param of params) {
            path += '/' + param;
          }
        }
    
        if (headers === undefined) {
          headers = new HttpHeaders();
        }
    
    
        if (type === 'get') {
          result = this.http.get(API_URL + '/' + path);
        } else if (type === 'post') {
          result = this.http.post(API_URL + '/' + path, data, {headers});
        } else if (type === 'delete') {
          result = this.http.delete(API_URL + '/' + path, {headers});
        } else if (type === 'put') {
          result = this.http.put(API_URL + '/' + path, data, {headers});
        }
    
    
    
        return result.pipe(
          tap(
            (response: ApiResponse) => {
              // console.log(response);
              return {...response};
            }),
          catchError(this.handleError())
        );
      }
```

I am using the method apiCall like this: `apiCall('get', 'http://localhost:8080/mypath', [], {}).subscribe(response => console.log(response);`

The same code is working in another project, but in this one I get the error described above.

I looked and saw that the error is on this line of http.mjs:

```
req.headers.forEach((name, values) => xhr.setRequestHeader(name, values.join(',')));
```

When I inspected the req object I saw that the headers has 1 element, exactly the same as in the application that is working.

I can't seem to figure it out

**EDIT:**

To make everything easier I tried to use the HttpClient get request directly, so I added this to the ngOnInit() of my component:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/cryptonews/user/news?from=0&to=10').subscribe(response => {
      console.log('response');
      console.log(response);
    });
```

where http is an instance of HttpClient.

However, I get the same error

Comment: You could try to remove the headers from your call and see if that helps.

Comment: I already did. You see, there is no headers in the 'get' request I'm calling. Same result

Comment: Any interceptors in the system?

Comment: Nope. There is none

Comment: for ```values.join(',')``` to work, values needs to be an array, but it is empty. Can you see if the 1 header in your request is having values as an Array?

Comment: Actually inside the req object is a headers object than has an array called headers inside. This array inside is empty, but I get that this causes the problem. The strange thing is that in anothe project happens the exactly same thing. However, it doesnt throw this error